# Extjs4 Button rednerer in grid dom is null error

Tags: html, dom, button, extjs4, renderer

i am facing a problem which i want to generate a button in grid column by using reconfigure function.
i find my code consist of the Extjs error during renderer function 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null'
i checked that it should be come from "renderTo: id3", do you have any idea on it? Do i do something wrong in my render button function in the grid?
Although i pop up error message, but the UI still can show the button i genereated. it is very confused.

```
var createColumns = function (json) {
var keys = getKeysFromJson(json[0]);
return keys.map(function (field) {
    if(field!='unread'&&field!='linkerType'&&field!='linkParam'&&field!='refNumber'&&field!='oid'&&field!='refOwner'){
    return {
        text: Ext.String.capitalize(field),
        //flex : 1,
        dataIndex: field,
        sortable: true,
        menuDisabled: true,
        renderer: function (val, metadata, record) {
                if(field=='action') {
                var str = val.split(":");
                metadata.style = "text-align: left";
                if(str[2]=='true'&&str[1]=='false'){
                    var id3 = Ext.id();
                    Ext.defer(function () {
                        Ext.widget('button', {
                            renderTo: id3,
                            margin: '0 0 0 10',
                            iconAlign: 'center',
                            tooltip:'Ok to Ship Again',
                            cls: 'x-btn-default-small',
                            text: '<img src="images/OKToShipAgain.png">',
                            handler: function() {
                                items=[];
                                items.push({ 
                                    "oid"       : record.get('oid'),
                                    "refNumber" : record.get('refNumber'),
                                    "refOwner"  : record.get('refOwner')
                                });
                                Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: '#{csMenuBean.contextPath}/ws3/todolistservice/submitOktoship',
                                    params: {data: Ext.encode(items)},
                                    success : function(response){
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        })
                    }, 50);
                    return Ext.String.format('<span id="{0}"></span>', id3);
                }
```

Comment: Can you set breakpoints inside the renderer in a web browser and see what line is generating the error?

Comment: i got the problem. it is because the renderer function run twice and it cause the dom problem of missing button. Just find that it is a bug in extjs.